# Flutter WillPopScope await for Popup Disappear

Tags: flutter

I Wrapped my Widget tree with WillPopScope and I want to show Popup Dialog which shows users to Exit from the app or not but at the same time, I have to use if()else{} condition. When I use this condition my logic works fine but didn't return anything.

**What is trying to Achieve:**

when someone clicks on the back press it checks the condition if it's true then Popup Appear and after the popup disappears it return some boolean value to WillPopScope but when the popup disappears WillPopScope didn't do anything.

I tried different solutions but didn't work for me.

**Here's my code back press**

```
backPressed() {
    if (isCollapsed) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          title: Text(
            'Are you sure you want to close this App?',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Text('Exit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  print("Return True");
                  return true;
                }),
            RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Text('Dismiss'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                  print("Return False");
                  return false;
                }),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      menuButton();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**WillPopScope Code is:**

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => backPressed(),
      child:
```

Comment: `showDialog` returns a `Future` - use it as a return value of `onWillPop` callback

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code?

Comment: `return showDialog(...)` - btw you can shorten your code to `onWillPop: backPressed,`

Comment: yes, my problem solved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this problem. Just Use Future

**Here's my solution**

WillPopScope Code:

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return await backPressed();
      },
      child:
```

my back press code:

```
  Future<bool> backPressed() async {
    if (isCollapsed) {
      bool value = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          title: Text(
            'Are you sure you want to close this App?',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Text('Exit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  print("Return True");
                  return true;
                }),
            RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                ),
                child: Text('Dismiss'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                  print("Return False");
                  return false;
                }),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return value;
    } else {
      menuButton();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you dont need `bool value = await showDialog(` just call `return showDialog(`

Comment: `Future<bool> foo(BuildContext ctx) async {
return showDialog(context: ctx, builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(actions: [
TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true), child: Text('true')),
TextButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false), child: Text('false')),
],));
}`

Comment: Okay. I understand thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {return await backPressed();

},
      child:
```

Change your Code to this . it will work now . thanks